# How to determine the hostname from an IP address in a Windows network?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ip, hostname

My LAN has 50 Windows hosts. At the Windows command line I try
ping   to get the IP address of a running Windows machine.

The question is how to get hostname of a specific IP address in the same Windows workgroup?

Another question is how to know the hostname of Windows machine from a Linux box if I have an IP address? Which command do you use? I have one host running Kubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you want to determine the name of a Windows machine without DNS, you should try [Nbtstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nbtstat). But that will only work on Windows:

For example,

```
NBTSTAT -A 10.10.10.10
```

On Linux, you should try [nmblookup](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/nmblookup.1.html) that does nearly the same:

```
nmblookup -A 10.10.10.10
```

Comment: NBTSTAT does rely on having NetBIOS loaded and running, which is often switched off in larger organisations with their own AD & DNS infrastructure. Probably a safe assumption here though with  a 50 machine workgroup.

Comment: Thanks you Decca, the nbtstat is rock
btw ... I failed on Linux box
nmblookup 192.168.1.92 
querying 192.168.1.92 on 192.168.1.255 
name_query failed to find name 192.168.1.92

Comment: The command nmblookup -A 192.168.1.92 is working sucessfully

Comment: `nmblookup` is part of my distro's Samba package. Not sure why `nmblookup` that does ip to hostname is part of Samba (networked file system code and print services code).

Answer (score 67):

The technically preferable method is to type `nslookup <ip address>`

NSLOOKUP actually asks the DNS server for the IP address of the hostname.  Ping will use the local *DNS Resolver Cache*, which may be incorrect until you flush.

Comment: that's assuming he has an internal dns server for name resolution. also, the op stated that he wanted to resolve a host name from the ip, so i'm assuming he doesn't know the host name to begin with. also, as far as i'm concerned there's no correct or incorrect way of doing it. there are multiple methods, each of which are valid, and each of which may produce different results.

Comment: Nope.  Using PING is not the best way of doing it.  You can do an `nslookup <ip address>` and it will resolve the reverse lookup.

Comment: i didn't say ping was the best way, i said it was a way. using nslookup assumes that he has an internal dns infrastructure in place. i didn't make that assumption as he mentioned workgroup in his post.

Comment: You refer to NSLOOKUP like it's some internal resolution tool...  Either way, NSLOOKUP is the technically superior option.

Comment: But he is correct.  nslookup is only of use in this scenario if there is a DNS server (whether that be internal or external) which has reverse lookup zone entries for the OP's hosts, and the OP's machines are configured to use that DNS server.

Comment: @mh& @izzy: i'm not debating that nslookup is not the proper tool to use. nslookup is the tool i would use in my environment where i know i have dns set up. i would use it for testing external dns resolution also, but as the op didn't give us enough detail, my answer was based on what was likely to give him some kind of result. maybe he'll post back with more info.

Comment: @Izzy I registered as a new member just to say thanks for the tip for NSLOOKUP, Izzy.  Out of all the stuff above, it's the only one that worked for me.  Thanks a million. --Jeff Moden

Answer (score 12):

On Windows you can use `ping -a x.x.x.x` to attempt to resolve the hostname from the [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address).

Comment: PING can result in inaccurate results, especially if you're actively working on DNS issues.

Comment: the op didn't state he was working on dns issues, he he implied that he was working on name resolution issues. dns is not the only name resolution mechanism in windows and is not a required name resolution mechanism. he also stated he's working in a workgroup setting so i didn't make any assumption regarding his having a dns infrastructure in place.

Comment: DNS is actually required for Active Directory.  We simply don't have enough info to say anything definitive regarding that.

Comment: @mh: yes it is, but again... not enough info from the op.

Comment: thank you all !
I don't have Active Directory service, I have one DNS server resolve for dhcp, mail, web server in my company, most of the employee host are running windows XP and using the same WORKGROUP.

Comment: @joeqwerty Nice gravitar. Seriously.

Comment: LOL. Homestar Runner.

Comment: @Izzy, What do you mean by "PING can result in inaccurate results, especially if you're actively working on DNS issues"?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways of doing it on both Windows and Linux. For example,

1. **nslookup**: the classic way to find the IP address from a hostname or vice-versa.
2. **ipconfig** or **ifconfig** based on whether you are running on Windows or Unix
3. **hostname -i** on Linux

Ref: [Multiple ways to get IP address from hostname in Linux and Windows](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/find-hostname-from-ip-address-to.html)

Answer (score 5):

For mac users `smbutil -v status -ae x.x.x.x` works. You can also use `arp -a` to get mac addresses for everything on your network.

Answer (score 1):

[nmblookup](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/nmblookup.1.html) might not work well for Linux hosts, because the [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) name is deprecated. And on Windows, it is limited to the local network.

Comment: No, that's wrong.  Netbios is (sadly) not deprecated, and actually required for a number of vital Active Directory functions.

Comment: Can somebody point out how in which cases AD DS still relies on Netbios? There have been talks that Netbios bound to be depricate since Windows Server 2003 times. Does it still somehow required now with Windows Server 2012 AD DS networks?

Comment: Sadly, yes: https://serverfault.com/questions/676867/error-adding-child-active-directory-domain-to-existing-forest